# How to add custom html or buttons to ActiveAdmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have models A and B. A has_many B. In the edit view for A I am 
displaying all of it's B children using

```
f.inputs  :for => :bs do |b|...
```

What I want to do is add a 'delete' link or button after ever 
B child of A. At the end of the list of B's I'd like to add a 'Add B' 
button which would create a new B instance and associate it with the 
current A. This way I can avoid an additional edit view for B (B is a 
very simple model).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to create a custom form partial. You do this by creating a file called 'app/views/admin/_as.html.erb'. Here you can create you form like you would a normal view, starting with:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @a] do |f| %>
...
<%= link_to 'Delete', admin_b_path, :id => b.object.id, :action => :destroy %>
```

Then in 'app/admin/as.rb' you just need to add the line:

```
form :partial => "a"
```

In this contrived example 'a' is my A class so replace it where necessary.

Comment: The consensus here: "ActiveAdmin is really great… at first." I already said this on a similar question, but it seems completely backwards that you have to rewrite your forms outside the ActiveAdmin DSL if you want one line of custom markup…